# Correct CNAME Administration

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, plesk

first time posting here!

So usually I do not have any issues resolving problems or questions due to the huge collection of KB articles and forum posts.

However, either I am totally misunderstanding something or what I am trying to accomplish it simply not possible.

I want to setup autoconfig and autodiscovery for my hosting clients. So far I managed to get autoconfig working via autoconfig.skylayer.eu. This means when someone enters any email address associated with skylayer.eu into Thunderbird, the connection settings are being filled out correctly. I achieved this following several tutorials from which I pieced together bits and pieces.

Now I would like to have every domain hosting on my plesk instance to call upon http://autoconfig.skylayer.eu/mail/config-v1.1.xml

As far as I understood this is achievable by entering a CNAME record, e.g. autoconfig.slyman.eu. However, when visiting autoconfig.slyman.eu one is redirected to skylayer.eu and I can't figure out why. Obviously Thunderbird is then unable to get the correct file.

I also tried to test a different CNAME: webmail.sebastian-tschamler.de which is supposed to go webmail.skylayer.eu but also redirects to skylayer.eu.

So I believe I am doing something entirely wrong but can't figure out what.

What am I missing? Any hint into the right direction is greatly appreciated. If you need any more info please do ask.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Interesting problem! 1) Do you have a service hosted behind the CNAME records you're creating? I don't believe it is enough to just make the CNAME record without putting an IP or address there for it to resolve to. Maybe your domain provider has auto redirects if no service is present? 2) How long have you waited after creating the CNAME? I have experienced delays of multiple hrs before being able to hit the CNAME without auto redirect in the past.

Comment: Control panels aren't very liked here. However, narrowing your problem to the cpanel-free part could make it ontopic.

Answer (score 1):

As these are all subdomains, using `CNAME` records is fine. But DNS record, `A` or `CNAME`, alone is not enough. You also need to configure your web server.

You need to have `ServerAlias` for every domain, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName autoconfig.skylayer.eu
    ServerAlias autoconfig.example.com autoconfig.example.net

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```